# Blackberry setting permission to inject events (esc button to jump back to app)

Tags: events, blackberry, camera, inject

I am taking photo by invoking the camera, and as many have explained I get back to the app using...

```
                        EventInjector.KeyEvent inject = new EventInjector.KeyEvent(EventInjector.KeyEvent.KEY_DOWN, Characters.ESCAPE, 0);
                        inject.post();
                        inject.post();
```

... in a FileSystemJournalListener.

This works on the simulator but does not on my device (Bold 9900). How do I set the permission for the app programatically so that this will work on a device without the user having to set permissions manually?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to test for the permissions you have, then request the ones you don't have but need. Here's a hint. Don't be a shmuck like so many other app developers. Ask for permissions on first run and take what you're given. If you aren't given a permission that you need inform the user that you can't run without that permission, and give them the option of going through your permission dialog again. If you don't get a permission which is not critical, and InputSimulation is far to dangerous a permission IMHO to be considered critical to put the camera away, run but inform the user (at the appropriate time) that s/he has to do some manual stuff. Like put the camera away after taking a picture.

The classes you will need to use are ApplicationPermission, ApplicationPermissionManager and ReasonProvider.